# Galois group of irreducible quartic with real coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a subfield of the real numbers and $f\in K[x]$ be an irreducible quartic. If $f$ has exactly two real roots, show that the Galois group of $f$ is $S_{4}$ or $D_{4}$ (I'm using the convention that this has order 8).

I don't really have an idea for this. All I can say is the other two roots are a complex conjugate pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is irreducible, then it's Galois group acts transitively. Now the transitive subgroups of $S_4$ are $S_4$, $A_4$, $D_4$, $C_4$, and $C_2\times C_2$. If $f$ has exactly two real roots, then it has two complex roots, and complex conjugation is an element of it's Galois group.

Which of the above five groups have transpositions as elements?

Comment: I see. $S_{4}$ and $D_{4}$ are the only ones.

Comment: @learner Indeed. :) Even if you weren't to know which subgroups contain transpositions, complex conjugation is an odd permutation, so it can't be $A_4$ or its subgroup $C_4$. To rule out $C_2\times C_2$, which is generated by the $4$-cycle $\sigma=(1,2,3,4)$, simply write down what $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^3$ are in cycle notation, and see that neither are transpositions.

Comment: I wonder if there's a mixup here? If C4 is the cyclic group on 4 elements, that would be generated by a 4 cycle (which is of order 4). But a C2 x C2  subgroup would instead be generated by 2 disjoint 2-cycles, for example.

Comment: $C_2\times C_2$ can either be of the form $\{e,(1~2)(3~4), (1~3)(2~4),(1~4)(2~3)\}$ or of the form $\{e,(1~2),(3~4),(1~2)(3~4)\}$. The difference is that the first form is transitive and the second form is not, but the transitive form does not contain a transposition.